# How can I display particular content with vertical menu button with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to display a particular `div` content with particular menu but my code is not showing like that. For the reference attached screenshot.(only with CSS). I don't want to use JS. When I am hovering on particular menu then all `div` content are displaying. And design is not looking good.
Here is my code:

```
<style>
.menu {
  height: 24%;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-family: calibri, monospace;
}
div.menu .button {
padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
 display:block;
cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: 600;
}
div.menu .button:hover {
padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
 display:block;
cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.menu .content {
 position:absolute;
  display:none;
  width: 440px;
  height: 23%;
  margin-left: 155px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  
}
.menu .content:hover {
left:150px;
    top:0px;
   color:black;
  display:block;
  
}

.menu .button:hover:focus:active ~ div.content {
  display: block;
}



html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>

<body>

 <div class="menu">
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">Home</div>
        <div class="content">
            “A house is made of bricks and beams. A home is made of hopes and dreams. Home is where our story begins…”
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">Contact</div>
        <div class="content">
            “Contacts added but not one is worthy enough to remain as their priority.”
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">About</div>
        <div class="content">
            “To be yourself in a world that is constantly trying to make you something else is the greatest accomplishment.”
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3EvV.png) is my image link.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```css
.menu {
  height: 24%;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-family: calibri, monospace;
  position:relative;
}
div.menu .button {
  padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: 600;
}
div.menu .button:hover {
  padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.menu .content {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  width: 440px;
  opacity:0;
  margin-left: 155px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  
}
.menu .button:hover+.content {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity:1;
  transition:display 3s;
  top:0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="menu">
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">Home</div>
        <div class="content">
            “A house is made of bricks and beams. A home is made of hopes and dreams. Home is where our story begins…”
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">Contact</div>
        <div class="content">
            “Contacts added but not one is worthy enough to remain as their priority.”
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="button">About</div>
        <div class="content">
            “To be yourself in a world that is constantly trying to make you something else is the greatest accomplishment.”
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```